# Decode a Websocket mask

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to write a function to decode a masked buffer sent to a node server via a WebSocket connection. Using a combination of RFC6455 and a few old SO answers, this is what I've managed so far:

```
function decodeMessage(buffer) {

    const opCode = buffer.readUInt8(0) & 0xF;

    if(opCode === 0x1) {
        const data_length = buffer.readUInt8(1) & 0x7F;
        let decoded = Buffer.alloc(data_length);

        const mask_key = buffer.readUInt32BE(2);

        for (let i = 0; i < data_length; i++) {
            decoded[i] = buffer.readUInt8(i) ^ mask_key[i % 4];
        }

        buffer.copy(decoded, 0, 2);

        return decoded.toString('utf8');

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

There's two issues with this code:

- It doesn't unmask the message correctly and just outputs garbled Unicode
- It outputs a different decoded message every time, even if the input is constant

(The payload length will never be longer than 126, so it doesn't need to worry about handling additional bytes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By modifying a function from [this post](https://hackernoon.com/implementing-a-websocket-server-with-node-js-d9b78ec5ffa8), I was able to get this working:

```
function decodeMessage(buffer) {

    if((buffer.readUInt8(0) & 0xF) === 0x1) {
        const length = (buffer.readUInt8(1) & 0x7F)+4;

        let currentOffset = 2;
        const mask_key = buffer.readUInt32BE(2);

        const data = Buffer.alloc(length);

        for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < length; ++i, j = i % 4) {
            const shift = j === 3 ? 0 : (3 - j) << 3;

            const mask = (shift === 0 ? mask_key : (mask_key >>> shift)) & 0xFF;
            const source = buffer.readUInt8(currentOffset++);
            data.writeUInt8(mask ^ source, i);
        }

        return data.toString('utf8');

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```